# Installing SQL Server 2012 error

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows

I am installing SQL Server 2012 on Windows 7 Enterprise on a company laptop.

I am getting

> SQL Server Setup failure
>
> An invalid return code was encountered waiting for a program to execute. The command being executed was "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\csc.exe" /noconfig /fullpaths @"C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Local\Temp\jdswqn6q.cmdline"..

And I didn't see anything in event viewer when i elevated the permission installation failed again and i got the following in install log

```
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:03 Slp: Running Action: FinalCalculateSettings  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp: Error: Action "Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.FinalCalculateSettingsAction" threw an exception during execution.  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp: Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionExecutionException: There was a failure to calculate the applicability of setting ALLINSTANCES. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.CalculateSettingApplicabilityException: There was a failure to calculate the applicability of setting ALLINSTANCES. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.CalculateSettingChangeabilityException: There was a failure to calculate the changeability of setting ALLINSTANCES. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.UnableRetrieveConfigObjectForSettingException: Unable to retrieve a public configuration object type Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.SlpInputSettings for setting ALLINSTANCES. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.ChainerInfrastructureException: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp: error CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\Users\jjohn027\AppData\Local\Temp\ko-vm0st.dll' -- 'The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid. '  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:  ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp: error CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\Users\jjohn027\AppData\Local\Temp\ko-vm0st.dll' -- 'The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid. '  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.DeserializeObject(String rootPath, Type type, String elementXPath)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.DeserializeObject(String rootPath, Type type, String elementXPath)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.DeserializeObject(String rootPath, Type type)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SettingBridge.GetHostingObject()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SettingBridge.GetHostingObject()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SettingBridge.ChangeabilityByUser()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Deployment.PrioritizedPublishing.PublishingQueue.CallFunctionWhileAutosubscribing[T](SubscriberDelegate subscriberDelegate, Int32 priority, AutosubscribingFunctionDelegate`1 function)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Setting.CalculateChangeabilityByUser()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Setting.CalculateChangeabilityByUser()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Deployment.PrioritizedPublishing.PublishingQueue.CallQueuedSubscriberDelegates()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Deployment.PrioritizedPublishing.PublishingQueue.Publish(Publisher publisher)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Setting.CalculateApplicability()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Setting.CalculateApplicability()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingService.CalculateAllSettings(Boolean chainerSettingOnly)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.FinalCalculateSettingsAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(TextWriter statusStream, ISequencedAction actionToRun, ServiceContainer context)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(TextWriter statusStream, ISequencedAction actionToRun, ServiceContainer context)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper(WorkflowObject metaDb, ActionKey action, ActionMetadata actionMetadata, TextWriter statusStream)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.InvokeAction(WorkflowObject metabase, TextWriter statusStream)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.PendingActions.InvokeActions(WorkflowObject metaDb, TextWriter loggingStream)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionEngine.RunActionQueue()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp: Error: Action "Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.BootstrapExtension.ExecuteWorkflowAction" threw an exception during execution.  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp: Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionExecutionException: There was a failure to calculate the applicability of setting ALLINSTANCES. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.CalculateSettingApplicabilityException: There was a failure to calculate the applicability of setting ALLINSTANCES. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.CalculateSettingChangeabilityException: There was a failure to calculate the changeability of setting ALLINSTANCES. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.UnableRetrieveConfigObjectForSettingException: Unable to retrieve a public configuration object type Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.SlpInputSettings for setting ALLINSTANCES. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.ChainerInfrastructureException: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp: error CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\Users\jjohn027\AppData\Local\Temp\ko-vm0st.dll' -- 'The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid. '  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:  ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp: error CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\Users\jjohn027\AppData\Local\Temp\ko-vm0st.dll' -- 'The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid. '  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.DeserializeObject(String rootPath, Type type, String elementXPath)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.DeserializeObject(String rootPath, Type type, String elementXPath)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.DeserializeObject(String rootPath, Type type)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SettingBridge.GetHostingObject()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SettingBridge.GetHostingObject()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SettingBridge.ChangeabilityByUser()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Deployment.PrioritizedPublishing.PublishingQueue.CallFunctionWhileAutosubscribing[T](SubscriberDelegate subscriberDelegate, Int32 priority, AutosubscribingFunctionDelegate`1 function)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Setting.CalculateChangeabilityByUser()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Setting.CalculateChangeabilityByUser()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Deployment.PrioritizedPublishing.PublishingQueue.CallQueuedSubscriberDelegates()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Deployment.PrioritizedPublishing.PublishingQueue.Publish(Publisher publisher)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Setting.CalculateApplicability()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Setting.CalculateApplicability()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingService.CalculateAllSettings(Boolean chainerSettingOnly)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.FinalCalculateSettingsAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(TextWriter statusStream, ISequencedAction actionToRun, ServiceContainer context)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(TextWriter statusStream, ISequencedAction actionToRun, ServiceContainer context)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper(WorkflowObject metaDb, ActionKey action, ActionMetadata actionMetadata, TextWriter statusStream)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.InvokeAction(WorkflowObject metabase, TextWriter statusStream)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.PendingActions.InvokeActions(WorkflowObject metaDb, TextWriter loggingStream)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionEngine.RunActionQueue()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.Workflow.RunWorkflow(WorkflowObject workflowObject, HandleInternalException exceptionHandler)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.BootstrapExtension.ExecuteWorkflowAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(TextWriter statusStream, ISequencedAction actionToRun, ServiceContainer context)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper(WorkflowObject metaDb, ActionKey action, ActionMetadata actionMetadata, TextWriter statusStream)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.InvokeAction(WorkflowObject metabase, TextWriter statusStream)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.PendingActions.InvokeActions(WorkflowObject metaDb, TextWriter loggingStream)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp: Received request to add the following file to Watson reporting: C:\Users\jjohn027\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp400E.tmp  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp: The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp: Inner exceptions are being indented  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:   
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp: Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.CalculateSettingApplicabilityException  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:     Message:   
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:         There was a failure to calculate the applicability of setting ALLINSTANCES.  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:     HResult : 0x85640002  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:         FacilityCode : 1380 (564)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:         ErrorCode : 2 (0002)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:     Data:   
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:       SettingId = ALLINSTANCES  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:       WatsonData = Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.CalculateSettingApplicabilityException@2  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:     Stack:   
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Setting.CalculateApplicability()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingService.CalculateAllSettings(Boolean chainerSettingOnly)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.FinalCalculateSettingsAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(TextWriter statusStream, ISequencedAction actionToRun, ServiceContainer context)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:     Inner exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.CalculateSettingChangeabilityException  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:         Message:   
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                 There was a failure to calculate the changeability of setting ALLINSTANCES.  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:         HResult : 0x85640003  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                 FacilityCode : 1380 (564)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                 ErrorCode : 3 (0003)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:         Data:   
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:           SettingId = ALLINSTANCES  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:           WatsonData = Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.CalculateSettingChangeabilityException@3  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:         Stack:   
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Setting.CalculateChangeabilityByUser()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Deployment.PrioritizedPublishing.PublishingQueue.CallQueuedSubscriberDelegates()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Deployment.PrioritizedPublishing.PublishingQueue.Publish(Publisher publisher)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Setting.CalculateApplicability()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:         Inner exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.UnableRetrieveConfigObjectForSettingException  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:             Message:   
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                         Unable to retrieve a public configuration object type Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.SlpInputSettings for setting ALLINSTANCES.  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:             HResult : 0x85640007  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                         FacilityCode : 1380 (564)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                         ErrorCode : 7 (0007)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:             Data:   
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:               SettingId = ALLINSTANCES  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:               ConfigObjectType = Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.SlpInputSettings  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:               WatsonData = Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.UnableRetrieveConfigObjectForSettingException@7  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:             Stack:   
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SettingBridge.GetHostingObject()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SettingBridge.ChangeabilityByUser()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Deployment.PrioritizedPublishing.PublishingQueue.CallFunctionWhileAutosubscribing[T](SubscriberDelegate subscriberDelegate, Int32 priority, AutosubscribingFunctionDelegate`1 function)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Setting.CalculateChangeabilityByUser()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:             Inner exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.ChainerInfrastructureException  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                 Message:   
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                                 Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                                 error CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\Users\jjohn027\AppData\Local\Temp\ko-vm0st.dll' -- 'The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid. '  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                                   
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                 HResult : 0x84b10001  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                                 FacilityCode : 1201 (4b1)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                                 ErrorCode : 1 (0001)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                 Stack:   
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.DeserializeObject(String rootPath, Type type, String elementXPath)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.DeserializeObject(String rootPath, Type type)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SettingBridge.GetHostingObject()  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                 Inner exception type: System.InvalidOperationException  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                     Message:   
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                                         Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                                         error CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\Users\jjohn027\AppData\Local\Temp\ko-vm0st.dll' -- 'The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid. '  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                                           
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                     Stack:   
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                                         at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                                         at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                                         at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                                         at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                                         at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:24:04 Slp:                                         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.DeserializeObject(String rootPath, Type type, String elementXPath)  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:44 Slp: Watson Bucket 2   
 Original Parameter Values   

(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:44 Slp: Parameter 0 : SQL Server 2012@RTM@   

(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:44 Slp: Parameter 1 : Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Setting.CalculateApplicability   

(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:44 Slp: Parameter 2 : System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile   

(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:44 Slp: Parameter 3 : Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.CalculateSettingApplicabilityException@1380@2   

(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:44 Slp: Parameter 4 : System.InvalidOperationException@-2146233079   

(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:44 Slp: Parameter 5 : FinalCalculateSettings   

(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:44 Slp: Parameter 7 : Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.CalculateSettingApplicabilityException@2   

(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:44 Slp:   
 Final Parameter Values   

(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:44 Slp: Parameter 0 : SQL Server 2012@RTM@   

(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:44 Slp: Parameter 1 : 0x855F7E9B   

(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:44 Slp: Parameter 2 : 0x4F2D2386   

(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:44 Slp: Parameter 3 : 0xDF9CF790@1380@2   

(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:44 Slp: Parameter 4 : 0xE9BC3D64   

(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:44 Slp: Parameter 5 : FinalCalculateSettings   

(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:44 Slp: Parameter 7 : 0x295EC2DE   

(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:45 Slp: Sco: Attempting to write hklm registry key Microsoft SQL Server to file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20151207_142348\Registry_SOFTWARE_Microsoft_Microsoft SQL Server.reg_  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:45 Slp: Sco: Attempting to write hklm registry key Uninstall to file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20151207_142348\Registry_SOFTWARE_Microsoft_Windows_CurrentVersion_Uninstall.reg_  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:45 Slp: Sco: Attempting to write hklm registry key MSSQLServer to file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20151207_142348\Registry_SOFTWARE_Microsoft_MSSQLServer.reg_  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:45 Slp: Sco: Attempting to write hklm registry key Microsoft SQL Server to file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20151207_142348\Registry_SOFTWARE_Wow6432Node_Microsoft_Microsoft SQL Server.reg_  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:45 Slp: Sco: Attempting to write hklm registry key Uninstall to file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20151207_142348\Registry_SOFTWARE_Wow6432Node_Microsoft_Windows_CurrentVersion_Uninstall.reg_  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:45 Slp: Sco: Attempting to write hklm registry key MSSQLServer to file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20151207_142348\Registry_SOFTWARE_Wow6432Node_Microsoft_MSSQLServer.reg_  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:46 Slp: There was a failure to calculate the applicability of setting ALLINSTANCES.  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:47 Slp: Watson bucket for exception based failure has been created  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:47 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine   
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:47 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\110  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:47 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value EnableErrorReporting  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:47 Slp: WER: Successfully read app consent from registry Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\110\EnableErrorReporting=.  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:47 Slp: WER: Application level consent value '' was mapped to consent status 'WerConsentNotAsked'  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:47 Slp: WER: Result of the submission:: 'WerDisabled'  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:47 Slp: WER: Submitted 1 of 1 failures to the Watson data repository  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:47 Slp:   
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:47 Slp: ----------------------------------------------------------------------  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:47 Slp:   
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:47 Slp: Error result: -2057043966  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:47 Slp: Result facility code: 1380  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:47 Slp: Result error code: 2  
(01) 2015-12-07 14:40:47 Slp: SQM Service: Sqm does not have active session.
```

Still getting errors when running developer edition. I  am getting invalid return code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32632/discussion-between-jay-jay-jay-and-mr-brownstone).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From our conversation above it seems that the first issues was permissions based (not running the install under an administrative account). The second issue is because winzip is known to have issues unzipping the ISO, it is advised to use WinRAR or PowerISO to unzip it or mount the ISO directly:

See here for more info:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/15081532-1fb4-4d3d-9768-94bd9c5b5259/sql-server-2012-installation-problem?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade

**Edit based on chat conversation:**

It seems as though the system administrators have given you a copy of SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition. As your laptop is running Windows 7 Enterprise it does not meet the minimum requirements to complete the install. I'd go back to the system administrators and ask them for either Developer Edition or Standard Edition as these allow you to install on a desktop version of Windows.

System requirements for SQL Server 2012 Editions:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.110).aspx